# Screen recorder on linux equivalent to windows game hub

Tags: linux, screen-recording

**The functionalities that i want in the screen recorder**

1. start recording with a shortcut (without opening the app ex simplescreenrecorder)
2. a tray icon that will be visible when screen is recording or something like windows default screen recoder

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It seems to me that simplescreenrecorder should fulfill your needs. You can configure a key shortcut, which is by default Super + R. The application of course has to be loaded first. It has a tray icon too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OBS](https://obsproject.com/) should be what you're looking for. It supports keyboard shortcuts, you can easily record from within fullscreen applications like games, or just specific windows, record your microphone etc.